Getting wrong output after simple subtraction
How is it possible to get given output with code below?
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void solve() {
    int n = 1000000000;
    long long ans = n;
    ans = (ans * (ans + 1)) / 2;
    long i{0};

    while(true) {
        const auto num = pow(2, i++);
        if(num > n) {
            break;
        }
        cout << ans << " - " << (2 * num);
        ans -= 2 * num;
        cout << " = "<< ans << endl;
        if(i > 10){
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    solve();
    return 0;
}

Output:
500000000500000000 - 2 = 500000000500000000
500000000500000000 - 4 = 500000000500000000
500000000500000000 - 8 = 500000000500000000
500000000500000000 - 16 = 500000000500000000
500000000500000000 - 32 = 500000000500000000
500000000500000000 - 64 = 500000000499999936
500000000499999936 - 128 = 500000000499999808
500000000499999808 - 256 = 500000000499999552
500000000499999552 - 512 = 500000000499999040
500000000499999040 - 1024 = 500000000499998016
500000000499998016 - 2048 = 500000000499995968

I tried to subtract the required value from ans using the logic below:
int d = 1;
while(d <= n) {
    cout << res << " - " << d << endl;
    res -= 2 * d;
    d *= 2;
}

Where res has the same value as ans in the code snippet above.
Where am I going wrong?

Avoid using floating-point arithmetic for integer calculations whenever possible, don't use pow, just multiply.  Why? Because if you don't its inaccurate as you have seen.

I gets your point but my real question here is if I am subtracting 2 in the first line why I am getting the same result as written next to it, and it continues to happen for values till 32. A subtraction in ans reflects only after subtracting 64, why?

But removing the auto and using an int solves my problem.

Yep, because it becomes an Intger.  As to why its the same results is as to why its inaccurate, it really cares more about the numbers on the left than the right, its used to do big number vs big number, not big number versus tiny number.

A double can hold any integer perfectly up to about 2⁵³ Which is around 9 quadrillion. Which is a side effect of a 64-bit double only have 53 bits for its fractional part.
Values above that start to hit a limit in which:
<very large double> + <small value> != <value you you think it should be>
So once you get about 2⁵³, you're going to see x + 1 == x type weirdness.  Or as discussed here: floating point just seems broken.
Per wikipedia:

Between 2^52=4,503,599,627,370,496 and 2^53=9,007,199,254,740,992 the representable numbers are exactly the integers. For the next range, from 2^53 to 2^54, everything is multiplied by 2, so the representable numbers are the even ones, etc. Conversely, for the previous range from 2^51 to 2^52, the spacing is 0.5, etc.

The weird math you are seeing at 500 quadrillion and above is consistent with this.

For devs of this level, I would recommend starting with an easy to understand summary, before getting into details about bits: A double only holds the first 15 decimal digits. Everything after that is rounded to the nearest* "epsilon".  This understanding then lays the groundwork for the rest of your answer. *Technically the rounding mode is configurable, but this remains an easy to understand summary.

There are 3 things at play here:

The line const auto num = pow(2, i++); makes num a double.
When 2 operands are not of the same type, they will get converted to the same type. In this case, double has priority over long long, so they both get converted to double.
Because ans is so large, it exceedes the precision of double, so the smaller values of num gets lost after the operation.

There are multiple solutions. Some options:

Declare num as int or long long for example, like this: const int num = pow(2, i++);.
Cast num before the operation, like this: ans -= 2 * (int)num;.

